# How to get conditional number of decimal points in SELECT CASE

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

It always returns biggest decimal places value. In following example it always returns 4 decimal places.

```
     SELECT
     CASE 
     WHEN 1 = 1 THEN  ISNULL(CAST(1000 AS FLOAT), -1) 
     WHEN 1 = 2  THEN ISNULL(CAST(0.00400 AS NUMERIC(13, 4)), -1) 
     ELSE ISNULL(CAST(0.00400 AS NUMERIC(13, 1)), -1) END
```

Comment: That's because `1 = 1` will always evaluate to `true` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`CASE` is an *expression* that returns exactly one value and the data types of all possible return values must match (or be implicitly compatible).

If you want conditional decimal place formatting, do it on the client.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing "FROM SOURCE"

```
  SELECT
     CASE 
     WHEN myvalue = 1 THEN  ISNULL(CAST(1000 AS FLOAT), -1) 
     WHEN myvalue = 2  THEN ISNULL(CAST(0.00400 AS NUMERIC(13, 4)), -1) 
     ELSE ISNULL(CAST(0.00400 AS NUMERIC(13, 1)), -1) 
     END 

 from ( 
 select myvalue from (
 select  1  as myvalue
 union 
 select 2 as myvalue
 union 
 select 3 as myvalue
  union 
 select null as myvalue
 ) SourceTable
 ) MainQueryTable
```

working OK
you can run only this to see what results you must return into MainSelect

```
  select myvalue from (
    select  1  as myvalue
    union 
    select 2 as myvalue
    union 
    select 3 as myvalue
  union 
 select null as myvalue
   ) SourceTable
```

this returns: 
myvalue
--------
NULL
1
2
3

PLEASE NOTE THAT ISNULL in your CASE ISNULL(CAST(ZZZZ AS FLOAT), -1)
when myvalue = 1 THEN  CAN'T BE NULL is 1  NO NEED ISNULL
IS USELESS
BECAUSE YOU HAVE ELSE PART IN CASE